# Store information

Tags: python, python-3.x

im total newbie in python and programing and i dont know where i can get answer (or what i should learn).

I have raspberry pi with FM transmiter to wirless turn on and turn off AC power. For example sending sginal 123 turns on AC and signal 124 turns off. I wrote script that check text file ("check.txt"). If check.txt is 1 then send signal to turn off and write file check.txt to 0, else send signal to turn on and write 1 in text file.

So i have script to turn on and off AC power by FM transmiter. I know its very nooby way to do that. SO what is propper and better way to store information that script can use?

```
import os
check = open("controlswitch.txt", "r")
    if check.read() == "0":
    check.close()
    os.system("/home/pi/ac433/codesend 15341881")
    controlswitch = open("controlswitch.txt", "w")
    controlswitch.write("1")
    controlswitch.close()
else:
    check.close()
    os.system("/home/pi/ac433/codesend 15341873")
    controlswitch = open("controlswitch.txt", "w")
    controlswitch.write("0")
    controlswitch.close()
```

Comment: Well.. You can save it as a .json file...

Comment: So this is right way to do this? Change from txt to json? There is no other (faster, better, simpler solution?)

Comment: @EranMoshe: Sure - and you can also store it in an SQL database. However, for this simple binary setting even a JSON file would be overkill.

Comment: It all depends on your necessities! with such simple necessities anything would work.

Comment: I'll give you other advices though, use a with clause when reading and writing files. Also write explicit if else statments, if x == 1, elif x == 0, else raise Exception

Comment: thanks, so conclusion is i was close to clue :). bit strange because a lot of lines of code for very simple action. but ok, now i know that i should use json file with multiple settings for future apps. :) something like dynamic changing setting file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and store the temperature as some dictionary values into some log files
if the temp gets the range pass the signal make that switch on and off.

in the other way make it by time
Use some cron jobs to automate the AC to power On and Off

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
- Using [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) dictionary. Pass it using environment variables PARAM1=yes script.py
- Message Broker as Redis or/and other systems
- Files (be careful here with access and security parameters)

Each way can be used so it's only your choice here)